# Access two different LAN web servers using same Public IP Address

Tags: xampp, portforwarding

I am running websiteA.com on xampp server "A" and websiteB.com on xammp server "B"

I can connect static IP 123.123.12.12 to access websiteA.com but I want to use same ip to browse websiteB.com.

I forwarded my static IP i.e 123.123.12.12 to lan IP 192.168.01.101:8888(for website A.com)

Now I want to forward same static IP on different lan IP 192.168.01.105:8080 (for websiteB.com)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is all about programming. Questions about server and network administration are better asked at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: with a single public IP you can access as much service on different servers. What you must know is port-forwarding. try forwarding all incoming traffic on port 8080 to ip 192.168.0.105, port 8080 or you can say, doing DNAT.